# Do you need to file Information Disclosure Statements for US Provisional Apps?

Tags: provisional-application, uspto, inequitable-conduct, duty-of-disclosure

I would assume no based on the following from 37 CFR 1.56(a):

> The duty to disclose information exists with respect to each **pending claim** until the claim is cancelled or withdrawn from consideration, or the application becomes abandoned.

Comment: Could you be more explicit?

Comment: "Do you need to file an IDS on provisional apps?"

Comment: Ok that is clearer. Could you edit the question with that? Comments are not necessarily permanent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more than not necessary. It's not possible.

[37 CFR § 1.51(d)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/37/1.51) provides:

> Applicants are encouraged to file an information disclosure statement in nonprovisional applications. See § 1.97 and § 1.98. No information disclosure statement may be filed in a provisional application.

[MPEP § 609](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s609.html) discusses this a little more:

> Information Disclosure Statements (IDSs) are not permitted in provisional applications filed under 35 U.S.C. 111(b). See 37 CFR 1.51(d). Since no substantive examination is given in provisional applications, a disclosure of information is unnecessary. Any such statement filed in a provisional application will be returned or destroyed at the option of the Office.